# Как проверить значение в ini?

Tags: delphi, ini

Как проверить значение "да или нет"
('секция', 'ключ', 'значение')

Comment: Получить значение. Сравнить с заданными образцами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uses IniFiles; // Надо подключить этот юнит

with TIniFile.Create('settings.ini') do // Читаем из этого файла (может не существовать)
try
  // Читаем булево значение. Если его нет, то будет взято значение по умолчанию
  MyBooleanValue := ReadBoolean('Section', 'Key', False {default value});

  // Читаем строковое значение
  MySstringValue := ReadString('Section', 'Key', 'нет' {default value});
finally
  Free; // не забываем освободить
end;
```